# when i add tap gesture the pinch and pan does not work in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a functionality to tap and add a pin image over another background image and the background image should be able to zoom and pan this is the XAML code for this, here the pinch zoom is not working but tap event is working fine

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:POC"
         xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:Vapolia.Lib.Ui;assembly=XamarinFormsGesture"
         x:Class="POC.MainPage"
         Title="Main Page">
<ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <local:PinchAndPanContainer>
        <local:PinchAndPanContainer.Content >
            <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="AbsoluteLayoutForImage">
                <Image x:Name="FloorPlanImage" 
                Source="Capture2.png"
                HeightRequest="400"
                IsEnabled="True"
                InputTransparent="True"
                ui:Gesture.TapCommand2="{Binding TapCommand2}"/>//This Property
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </local:PinchAndPanContainer.Content>
    </local:PinchAndPanContainer>
</ScrollView>
```

in the cs file, this tap command is adding a pin image inside the absolute layout using the coordinates in Point.

```
public Command<Point> TapCommand2 => new Command<Point>(point =>
    {
        AddPin(point);
    });
```

Now if we just remove `ui:Gesture.TapCommand2="{Binding TapCommand2}"` this property from the above code pinch and pan works fine.

For Tap event I used Vapolia.XamarinFormsGesture NuGet package and for pinch and pan used xamarin forms Gesture Recognizer 
 Can anyone help

Comment: Hello Siddhant, welcome to StackOverflow just want to make sure about something are you trying to implement an image zoom functionality here?

Comment: Yes image zoom and pan functionality

Comment: Use this and try adding the pointer to it and see if it works in case it does let me know and i will update my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I did a similar functionality and ended up creating a CustomControl as below:

**Note:** I have used the FFImageLoadings CachedImage in my class in case you are not using FFImage just replace it with your defualt xamarin forms image.

And this has the following functionalities: PanSwipe, Zoom and DoubleTap to zoom.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using FFImageLoading.Forms;

public class ZoomableImage : CachedImage //In case not using ff image replace this with the Image control
{
    private const double MIN_SCALE = 1;
    private const double MAX_SCALE = 4;
    private const double OVERSHOOT = 0.15;
    private double StartScale, LastScale;
    private double StartX, StartY;

    public ZoomableImage()
    {
        var pinch = new PinchGestureRecognizer();
        pinch.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pinch);

        var pan = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        pan.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(pan);

        var tap = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 2 };
        tap.Tapped += OnTapped;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tap);

        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {
        Scale = MIN_SCALE;
        TranslationX = TranslationY = 0;
        AnchorX = AnchorY = 0;
        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Scale > MIN_SCALE)
        {
            this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
            this.TranslateTo(0, 0, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
        else
        {
            AnchorX = AnchorY = 0.5; //TODO tapped position
            this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.CubicInOut);
        }
    }

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                StartX = (1 - AnchorX) * Width;
                StartY = (1 - AnchorY) * Height;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                AnchorX = Clamp(1 - (StartX + e.TotalX) / Width, 0, 1);
                AnchorY = Clamp(1 - (StartY + e.TotalY) / Height, 0, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Status)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                StartScale = Scale;
                AnchorX = e.ScaleOrigin.X;
                AnchorY = e.ScaleOrigin.Y;
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:
                if (e.Scale < 0 || Math.Abs(LastScale - e.Scale) > (LastScale * 1.3) - LastScale)
                { return; }
                LastScale = e.Scale;
                var current = Scale + (e.Scale - 1) * StartScale;
                Scale = Clamp(current, MIN_SCALE * (1 - OVERSHOOT), MAX_SCALE * (1 + OVERSHOOT));
                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                if (Scale > MAX_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MAX_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                else if (Scale < MIN_SCALE)
                    this.ScaleTo(MIN_SCALE, 250, Easing.SpringOut);
                break;
        }
    }

    private T Clamp<T>(T value, T minimum, T maximum) where T: IComparable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0)
            return minimum;
        else if (value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
            return maximum;
        else
            return value;
    }
}
```

Good luck, 
In case of queries kindly revert.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code works great but I need to add another tap event on the image to get the tap coordinates, for which I am using Vapolia.XamarinFormsGesture nuget package . And when i'm doing that using this ui:Gesture.TapCommand2="{Binding TapCommand2}" property inside the Image view it is kind of overriding other gesture recognizer events.

Comment: In my understanding what you can do here is add that recognizor directly to the image control in the ontapped function i am using and since you dont want that tap functionality you dont need it anyway does that makes sense?

Comment: But the problem is this -  ui:Gesture.TapCommand2="{Binding TapCommand2}" is not a gesture recognizer its a Command which is creating a problem

Comment: Umm well then you can bind that command inside a gesture recognizor in your xaml

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Do you mean <TapGestureRecognizer ui:Gesture.TapCommand2="{Binding TapCommand2}"/> . This does'nt worked for me

Comment: Update your code with the latest changes in your question please

Comment: This is a great solution!  Thanks.  I just changed CachedImage to Image and used the code as is in an MVVM solution.  I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution from [FreakyAli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7462031/freakyali) in my MVVM app.  I just added his code as a .cs file in the ViewModels folder and referenced the new class in my XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:ImageViewModel"
                      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                      xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                      xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:BLE.Client.ViewModels;assembly=BLE.Client"
                      x:Class="BLE.Client.Pages.ImagePage" Title="View Image">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" >
      <viewModels:ZoomableImage x:Name="WaypointImage"
             Source="{Binding MyImage}"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      </viewModels:ZoomableImage>
    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
</views:MvxContentPage>
```

C#:

```
   private ImageSource _myImage;
   public ImageSource MyImage
   {
      get => _myImage;
      set
      {
         _myImage = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyImage);
      }
   }
```